# Equivalent of an 'AutoInsert' property for a datasource?

Tags: delphi, datasource

Sorry if the question seems vague, please let me explain.

I have two datasets, called, say, Master and Extensions. They have a same primary key, but not all Master records have an Extensions record (this is the important point).

The UI are the usual data aware controls linked by datasources, placed in a TPageControl, with a page/tab for each dataset. A TDBNavigator linked to the Master dataset allows the user to browse through the records.

The user could be on the Extensions page/tab while browsing, and may want to edit the Extensions record data. If an Extension record already exists, all's well and good because the AutoEdit property of the datasource will automatically place the dataset into edit mode.

But what if there is no Extensions record? I suppose I need the equivalent of an 'AutoInsert' property, that would automatically place the dataset in Insert mode if the user starts to typing in one of the controls. (and I can always set up the primary key in the BeforeInsert event).

Any thoughts how I would achieve this?

Thanks for any advice, and thanks for reading a long question,
Regards
PhilW.

Comment: AutoInsert doesn't feel right on a DataSource: it should be implemented on the editor that shows the actual record, because the editor can give the user an indication of what's going on. I'd expect a AutoInsert property on a Db Grid component. If you're showing the data using some sort of grid, look for an AutoInsert property over there; If you're using discrete editors just add an "Insert" button that's made visible only if the DataSource is EOF.

Comment: @Cosmin: thanks for your comment, but my users expect just to start typing in the TDBEdit controls, they would be confused if they have to click a button before 'editing', especially when it would only apply to some instances. Is there a way to hide this from the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would programmatically insert the record when the user enters any of the editable controls, and remove it afterwards if it's not needed. You should be able to do that without hitting the database at all, so the only real cost is a little code.

I don't think it's really autoinsert when you're inserting a new row into the middle of a sparse table like this.

Comment: +1. In the OnEnter event you can do: `if DataSet.Eof then DataSet.Append` then in the DataSet's BeforePost event you cab do `if (DataSet.State = dsInsert) and (AllFieldsDefaultValues) then DataSet.Cancel`

Comment: @moz: Yes, I think this is going to be the sensible approach. By the way, when I said 'AutoInsert' I meant it as like the existing 'AutoEdit' property of TDatasource, but using Insert; rather than meaning to automatically insert blank records in the Extensions dataset as the user browsed through the Master dataset.

Comment: @Andriy: I'm not afraid of a __little__ code; it's the testing, tweaking and then debugging, and then getting that sickening feeling in the pit of the stomach that you'd be rewriting it all within 6 months - that's the worry. <g>.

Comment: @Cosmin: Thanks; this is good. I like the (AllFieldsDefaultValues) concept.

Comment: @PhilW: Yeah, that dark side of software development certainly diminishes the pleasures of creating our software masterpieces. Otherwise I'm sure you wouldn't be afraid of lots of code either!

Comment: @PhilW: I think it should be quite testable with AutoKey and a small mock. If you don't already have stuff set up try using a memtable as your DB layer mock within DUnit, then AutoKey set to poke your form when it pops up (see "Activating and manipulating windows").

Comment: @Cosmin Prund: you're right, I should have put code hints in.